# Excel Interop Autofilter Range

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, autofilter

I need the following filter to work in C#.

Here is the working Macro in Excel VBA:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$XFC$13214").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= ">=1/1/2024", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=1/31/2024"
```

Here is what I thought was the C# equivalent:

```
excelRange.AutoFilter(Field: 6, Criteria1: ">=1/1/2024", Operator: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd, Criteria2: "<=1/25/2024");
```

But I get the following runtime error in C#:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: '_AutoFilter method of Range class failed'

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I left out an important piece of information. The Worksheet that the Range is working on was created by doing a Worksheet.Copy(). I did a little research and found the following quote which explains the problem I think:

> *Note
>
> Whether you copy the worksheet programmatically, or the end user
> copies the worksheet manually, there is no code behind the new
> worksheet and controls on the new worksheet do not function. This is
> because the newly copied worksheet is a Worksheet object and not a
> Worksheet host item. Windows Forms controls and host controls can only
> be added to host items. For more information, see Programmatic
> limitations of host items and host controls.

So I did the Filter on the Original first, then copied it and then closed the original without saving it and everything worked!